# Have Eclipse automatically import classes statically

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

When I'm creating JUnit tests Eclipse takes care of importing `assertEquals` for me automatically.

In my current code I often write statements like these:

```
Arrays.stream(columns).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Eclipse complains about the missing `toCollection()`:

> The method toCollection(ArrayList::new) is undefined for the type ...

When I manually add `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;` import at least this warning is gone. But I get a new warning:

> The import java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection is never used

So basically I have two questions:

- is there a way to automatically add the static import without manual intervention like Eclipse is able to do for me in case of assertEquals ?
- is there (besides adding @SuppressWarning) a way to get rid of the second warning about the unused import ?

If this matters: I use the current version of STS 4.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have static methods imported in the same way as `assertEquals`, add their classes to the list at: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favorites.

Eclipse will then propose static methods of those classes when you start typing.

On the unused import:
I do not see this behavior in my Eclipse. 
Instead, with
`import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;` 
and some use of `toCollection` in my code, such as:
`...collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new))`, 
there is no warning.

Note: if `toCollection` is refered to with it's class, such as:
`...collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))`, then Eclipse produces a warning on the static import of `toCollection`. This is correct, as the import is indeed not used (instead, an import of the Collectors class is used to resolve the class and the method). Could that be the case?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this, now it works. Do you want to expand your answer and explain the meaning of `new type` vs `new member` ?

Comment: New Type adds all static methods of that type to the favorites list. New member, on the other hand, only adds a particular method.